# WordPress async-upload.php 403 error

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, centos6

For a client of mine, I have moved their webpage to a **VPS** by request. But I'm a web developer and not good at server configuration.

Due to a permission misconfiguration, in my opinion, I cannot fetch images in **Media library**, no error or sth. Also when I try to upload a new one, it completes the **Uploading** process, but gets stuck in **Processing** process and gives a 403 error on async-upload.php.

I have tried **755** and **777** permissions on both **wp-content** and **wp-content/uploads**, doesn't solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Logs added.

These are from requests.log

```
*.252.164.35 - - [20/Nov/2015:18:14:48 -0500] "GET /xml_feed/********.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1861
*.252.164.35 - - [20/Nov/2015:18:14:51 -0500] "GET /xml_feed/*****.php HTTP/1.1" 200 394
*.252.164.35 - - [20/Nov/2015:18:14:52 -0500] "GET /xml_feed/***.php HTTP/1.1" 200 359
*.253.241.91 - - [20/Nov/2015:18:14:50 -0500] "POST /wp-admin/async-upload.php HTTP/1.1" 200 11
*.253.241.91 - - [20/Nov/2015:18:14:53 -0500] "POST /wp-admin/async-upload.php HTTP/1.1" 403 3214
```

**Edit 2:** Gave all folders **777** permission, now I can re-install my WP setup and update my plugins from panel, but Media Library problem still exists, async-upload.php still gives **403** error.

Comment: Check the Apache log, usually in `/var/log/httpd` for clues.  403 means you are forbidden to view the resource. Also check for an htaccess file and the virtual host configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf`

Comment: @Grasshopper thanks for reply. I edited my post, added logs.

Comment: @Grasshopper there is an IP difference between my xml_feed requests and WP's new media requests. Could it be the reason of the problem?

Comment: Gave all folders 777 permission, now I can re-install my WP setup and update my plugins from panel, but Media Library problem still exists, async-upload.php still gives 403 error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue for me was linked to an `auto_increment` issue on the database.

Here's what fixed it for me:

```
DELETE FROM wp_termmeta  WHERE meta_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_terms  WHERE term_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_term_taxonomy  WHERE term_taxonomy_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_commentmeta  WHERE meta_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_comments  WHERE comment_ID=0;
DELETE FROM wp_links  WHERE link_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_options  WHERE option_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta  WHERE meta_id=0;
DELETE FROM wp_users  WHERE ID=0;
DELETE FROM wp_posts  WHERE ID=0;
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta  WHERE umeta_id=0;

ALTER TABLE  wp_termmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_terms ADD PRIMARY KEY(term_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_term_taxonomy ADD PRIMARY KEY(term_taxonomy_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_commentmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_comments ADD PRIMARY KEY(comment_ID);
ALTER TABLE  wp_links ADD PRIMARY KEY(link_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_options ADD PRIMARY KEY(option_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_postmeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(meta_id);
ALTER TABLE  wp_users ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
ALTER TABLE  wp_posts ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID);
ALTER TABLE  wp_usermeta ADD PRIMARY KEY(umeta_id);

ALTER TABLE wp_termmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_terms CHANGE term_id term_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_term_taxonomy CHANGE term_taxonomy_id term_taxonomy_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_commentmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_comments CHANGE comment_ID comment_ID  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_links CHANGE link_id link_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_options CHANGE option_id option_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_postmeta CHANGE meta_id meta_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_users CHANGE ID ID  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_posts CHANGE ID ID  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE wp_usermeta CHANGE umeta_id umeta_id  BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

As taken from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225641/wordpress-database-lost-auto-increment)

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it for me, but I'd really like to know why. I tried looking in the code for what would throw the 403 header in response to the upload. The actual response was `-1` with an http response header 403. I was going crazy checking ownership and permissions, and searching the logs for clues that aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed servers I used a find and replace in my DB for the folder structure `/folder_name/public_html/blog` -> `/srv/www/html/blog`. This tool works pretty good [interconnect](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). I tried originally with find and replace in notepad but

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = '0' AND post_type = 'attachment';
```

OR

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) c FROM wp_posts GROUP BY ID HAVING c > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CloudFlare, it could be also a false positive from CloudFlare WAF.

It's easy to detect, check the request (for example with your browser devtools), and if you find a `cf-mitigated: challenge` header in response, go to CloudFlare dashboard to have details (Security/Events).